# Prevent persistent edited label after label edit in listview C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, windows-explorer

In my Winforms application, I want  to allow the user to edit listview items labels like how you would do when renaming files or folders in windows explorer. What I want to achieve now is the exact behavior that windows explorer behaves when you rename a file or folder.

In an attempt to achieve that effect, I called a method which renames the affected file/folder in the `AfterLabelEdit` event and then go on to repopulate my listview. If it matters, my listview is a virtual listview and therefore all my items are stored in a dictionary.

The issue I have now is that although the file renames properly and the listview gets updated as the new name is reflected in the list, The edited label stays persistent so now I see 2 listview items with the same name where one of them is a localized edited text whilst the other is the actual one. The resulting effect is that the localized label now represents a file with another name which the listview wont show.

Here is a snippet of my current logic:

```
    private void UpdateListView(int index, string NewName)
    {
        items[index] = NewName;
        items.Sort();
        listViewItemsList.Clear();

        foreach(string item in items)
        {
            ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem();
            Item.Text = item;
            listViewItemsList.Add(Item);
        }

        listView1.BeginUpdate();
        listView1.VirtualListSize = listViewItemsList.Count;
        listView1.EndUpdate();
    }

    private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string newName = e.Label;
        UpdateListView(e.Item, newName);
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can refresh my listview after the edit while removing the localized label text done by the label edit?

Edit: For those who would like to see the issue in action, feel free to download this project file and edit a label in the listView. Then, click on "Refresh" and the issue can be seen. I included a "Show Actual Data" button to see the list items without breakpoints and what I actually want the listview to show after editing a label. To ensure you see the issue, be sure to edit a label and give a new name such that it should rearrange when sorted alphabetically.

Download link for sample project: https://app.box.com/s/t24ej9hbokcr3qcg8nkbs8slknf5ez5w

Comment: I only read the last line in the question and am going to guess: do a `this.Invalidate()` or `ctrl.Invalidate()` to cause the Paint event to fire.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however it doesn't seem to work. I tried putting `Invalidate()` at the start and end of the `AfterLabelEdit` event but the result was still the same :(

Comment: Surely there is a CodeProject or MSDN that demonstrates this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-an-explorer-style-interface-with-the-listview-and-treeview and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5064/Implementing-a-common-File-system-browser-with-a-L, there will be others. If you want help it will be easier with a [MCVE]

Comment: @JeremyThompson I took a look at both of those resources you have linked and while they were certainly helpful in starting a file explorer from scratch, I couldn't find any resolution for my specific issue as those implementations did not have renaming functionalities. However, upon further digging around, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.afterlabeledit(v=vs.110).aspx according to that article, the edited text will only commit after the event. So I guess I'm screwed :/

Comment: If you can give us the MCVE/code specifically to repro this label editing, I'll take a look.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have created a new project with the issue that I am facing. Simply run and edit a label and you can see the problem. My goal is to make sure the listview stays updated and sorted alphabetically after any label editing. https://app.box.com/s/t24ej9hbokcr3qcg8nkbs8slknf5ez5w Mind any bad programming practices as I created this only for demo purposes.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I forgot to mention that to reproduce my specific issue, you should edit a label that is not the first or last and give it a new name (starting with another alphabet) such that it should rearrange after the edit as I want them to be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone who may come across this issue, I Managed to solve the issue by using `listView.BeginInvoke();` So my solution is run my `UpdateListView()` inside the `BeginInvoke()` method instead of within the `listView.AfterLabelEdit()` method as according to MSDN,

> Because the ListView.AfterLabelEdit event takes place before the label edit is committed, calling the ListView.Sort method in a handler for this event will sort the item using the original value.

So running my `UpdateListView()` code in the `ListView.AfterLabelEdit()` would result in the listview bug I mentioned in my question above. Do also note that in this case, my listview is in `virtualMode` so my listview is based off a List. Here is my latest code:

```
private void UpdateListView(int index, string NewName)
    {
            items[index] = NewName;
            items.Sort();
            listViewItemsList.Clear();

        foreach(string item in items)
        {
            ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem();
            Item.Text = item;
            listViewItemsList.Add(Item);
        }

        listView1.BeginUpdate();
        listView1.VirtualListSize = listViewItemsList.Count;
        listView1.EndUpdate();
    }

private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string newName = e.Label;
        listView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateListView(e.Item, newName)));
    }
```

I will update the code snippet in the original question so that there is more consistency and it will be easier to see the changes.